# Clone complex Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to make clone of very large and complex Hibernate entity with many @OneToMany, @OneToOne etc. relations, change some properties and store the cloned object to the database.

What I believe needs to be done is:

1. Fetch object from DB
2. Detach object from hibernate
3. Remove all primary and foreign keys(to be auto-generated again)
4. Update required properties
5. Persist detached object

Is this possible to do this in more elegant way? Is this approach even correct?
Table alone has over 50 columns, so the approach mentioned above is, in my opinion, very inefficient, hard to test etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952330/how-to-make-a-copy-of-hibernate-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan

Answer (score 4):

all 5 steps are correct. you just create a clone/copy of object. to copy fields you can use  [apache BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) or [spring BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html). Also if you copy not only one entity types you can create custom util class and annotation and use this copy/ignore annotation in fields. For future you can add some copy strategies like - lite ,  full copy , copy with replace....